Find the minimum and maximum values of $f(x,y)=1+\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})$?
Find the minimum and maximum value of $$f(x,y)=1+\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})$$
There are $2$ methods to find the minimum and maximum values of $f(x,y)$ as far as I think.
The first method is very simple.
$$-1\leq \sin(x^{2}+y^{2})\leq 1$$
$$\implies 0\leq 1+\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})\leq 2$$
Thus we can say that the minimum of $f(x,y)$ is $0$ and the maximum of $f(x,y)=2$.
The second method is bit tricky.
$$f(x,y)=1+\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})$$
$$\implies f_{x}=2x\cos(x^{2}+y^{2}),f_{y}=2y\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})$$
Now $f_{x}=0$ implies $2x\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})=0$ and $f_{y}=0$ implies $2y\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})=0$
which implies that $(0,0)$ is the stationary point (As mentioned in my friend's book)
Again
$A=f_{xx}=-4x^{2}\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})+2\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})$
$B=f_{xy}=-4xy\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})$
$C=f_{yy}=-4y^{2}\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})+2\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})$
Now at $(0,0)$ we get $A=2,B=0,C=2$ which implies $AC-B^{2}=4>0$
Thus we conclude that $A>0$ and $AC-B^{2}>0$ which implies $(0,0)$ is the minimum point.
Therefore the minimum value is equal to
$$f(0,0)=1$$
Question :
From the first method I got the minimum to be as $0$ and from the second method I got the minimum to be as $1$.
Which one is correct among $0$ and $1$ ?

Local minimum need not be a global minimum.

Ok. Thank you Pranay very much

The answer provided by the first method is right but the method itself is not.
You are showing 0 is a lower bound for your function but not all lower bounds are the minimum.
$-20 \leq f(x,y)$ but -20 is not the minimum! Minimum is a lowerbound that's achieved. You have to verify that there are $x,y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$.  This is the case for $x=y=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2} \pi}$. Same goes for maximum.
As for the second method, others have already pointed out, the second order condition only garantees local optimality, not global.

In polar form, $f(r)=1+\sin(r^2)$. Because $r^2$ can equal $3\pi/2+2k\pi$, $f$ reaches $0$, and it hits $2$ when $r^2=\pi/2+2k\pi$. At $r=0$, $f=1$, a local minimum but not the global one. Hence $\min=0$ and $\max=2$.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

I also think so @Raynard Bond but in my Friend's book the answer is given as $1$ not $0$. And also there is no mention of local and global minima.

One can integrate the gradient along closed loops, revealing multiple radii where $\cos(r^2)$ vanishes. At those points $\sin(r^2) = -1$, giving $f(r)=0$. Thus the global minimum is $0$. The point $(0,0)$ with $f=1$ is merely a local minimum. The global maximum is $2$.

Thank you @Raynard Bond very much
